# Javaparser add new field to class

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaparser

I would like to add a new field of type `List` to every existing field in a class. I would also like it to be initialized with an empty `ArrayList<Long>`. How can I create the appropriate `FieldDeclaration` object to add to list of `BodyDeclaration` in the class (`TypeDeclaration`) I've already extracted?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kind of old and you might already found an answer but since there is no answer here and this has troubled me some time before I found a way to do it so I will write down how I solved this problem.

Note: On JavaParser's [FAQ](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/FAQ) it explicitly states that it's intended to either use lazy initialization (in either getter or setter) to an empty list.
For more information on this please refer to the following issue:

- https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/3

Without further ado, here is how I worked around it:

```
String initString = "ArrayList<" + argType + ">()";
FieldDeclaration fd = new FieldDeclaration(
                            ModifierSet.PUBLIC, 
                            new ClassOrInterfaceType(className), 
                            new VariableDeclarator(
                                new VariableDeclaratorId(name, new NameExpr(initString))));
```

Where `className` is the collection's name (`List` in this case) and initialize another `ClassOrInterfaceType` instance to add `argType`. Then `fd` will produce the following:

```
public List<argType> parameters = new ArrayList<argType>();
```